# How to join two SELECT statements operating on the same column on a single table with different conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying complete the following exercise

> Create a query that has the employee name, supervisor name, and employee salary for each employee who works in the 'Research' department

Which operates on the following schema:

https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/23140228_10214571052854224_1441212020_n.png?oh=15f361ec2679373f2cfeb427dd5b6978&oe=59F9593B

I have developed the following query which works somewhat, but does not match the rows accordingly so I end up with a result consisting of the employee names and salaries, with separate rows for the manager names. My query is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW research AS
SELECT NULL as Fname, NULL as Lname, NULL as Salary, Lname as Manager from EMPLOYEE
WHERE Ssn IN (SELECT Superssn from EMPLOYEE WHERE Dno = (SELECT Dnumber from DEPARTMENT WHERE Dname = 'Research'))
UNION
SELECT Fname, Lname, Salary, Null as Manager  FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Dno = (SELECT Dnumber from DEPARTMENT WHERE Dname = 'Research');
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this? Am I going the right way about it by using the UNION command?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you counted ('s and )'s? Same number?

Comment: you need the same number of columns in both the select statements.
the columns need to have the same data type.

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
select
    emp.FName       as EmployeeFName
    ,emp.LName      as EmployeeLName
    ,sup.FName      as SupervisorFName
    ,sup.LName      as SupervisorLName
    ,emp.Salary     as Salary

from
    Employee emp
    inner join  Department dept
            on  emp.dno = dept.dnumber
    inner join  Employee sup
            on  emp.SuperSSN = sup.SSN

where
    dept.Name = 'Research'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't want UNION for this.

Why do you have `super_ssn` on EMPLOYEE and also `mgr_ssn` on DEPARTMENT? Isn't that redundant?

Anyway, here's another way to do it.

```
select fname, lname, salary, 
    (select lname from employee e where e.ssn = employee.superssn) manager
from employee
where dno = (SELECT Dnumber from DEPARTMENT WHERE Dname = 'Research');
```

Comment: I'm guessing that an employee's direct supervisor isn't necessarily the department manager, so it wouldn't be redundant.

Comment: That's what I thought too, the OP just used "manager" to refer to the supervisor so I was curious.